# How can I create a Polymorphic Ruby Method?

Tags: ruby, polymorphism

I have a class -- `AccountGroup` -- which has a polymorphic relation to various Account classes (i.e. `AwordsAccount`, `BingAccount`, etc...). I've defined a helper method -- `accounts` -- that aggregates all of the different account types:

```
def accounts
  adwords_accounts + bing_ads_accounts + facebook_accounts + linkedin_accounts
end
```

Now, I'd like to extend this method so that I can use it to add accounts as well as list them:

```
account_group.accounts << an_adwords_account
```

which should call:

```
account_group.adwords_accounts << an_adwords_account
```

under the hood.  How do I differentiate between calling the method with the modifier `<<` vs. calling it without the modifier?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the way you are hoping to do this will not work. `account_group.accounts << an_adwords_account` will just return the list of accounts, and then append the new account to the returned array. It won't actually modify the object's attributes or anything. You should really just create an `add_account` method, which then differentiates which account type

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would implement this. The `Account` model uses [single table inheritance](http://thibaultdenizet.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) and has a `type column` that distinguishes between the different account types:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account_group
end

class AdwordsAccount < Account
end

class BingadsAccount < Account
end

class FacebookAccount < Account
end

class LinkedinAccount < Account
end
```

In your AccountGroup model you can then create associations to all of these without any problems:

```
class AccountGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :adwords_accounts
  has_many :bingads_accounts
  has_many :facebook_accounts
  has_many :linkedin_accounts
end
```

Now everything works as expected and `accounts` contains all of the other types combined. You might need to call `reload` on the other associations when you add/remove accounts, but i'm not sure about that. Just try it out.

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately, the network accounts are quite different so we do need separate tables for all of them. So, this doesn't work for my use case.